# Getting an array in a django function

Tags: javascript, python, django

I send data from JS via JSON

```
var pricesum  = sumprice;
    var date = expirationdates;
    var price = prices;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "print",
        data: {
            'pricesum': pricesum, 'date': date,'price': price,
        },
```

They have the following form

[image]

```
expirationdate = request.POST.get('date', False);
    price =request.POST.get('price', False);
    print(expirationdate)
    print(price)
```

Next, I get them in the django function, but I always get false. How do I get them correctly so that they are all in the array?

I'm trying

```
 expirationdate = request.POST.get('date[]', False);
    price =request.POST.get('price[]', False);
```

But I get only the last element of the array date and price

```
[('pricesum', '3600'), ('date[]', '2021-05-06'), ('price[]', '900')]
```

Comment: What is the output of `request.POST` ? Or keys from `request.POST.keys()` or even its items with `request.POST.items()` ?

Comment: What do you mean? If I try to print the variables I get false

Comment: I mean `request.POST` is a QueryDict object and thus contain (key,value) pairs. Printing this object and the elements it contains will help you understand why you get `False`. Maybe keys are not exactly what you expect (keys might have a trailing space for instance...).

Comment: How exactly do I need to print them out to view them?

Comment: What about `print(request.POST.items())` ? Leave the output below.

Comment: Which argument should be specified in parentheses? If I do print (request.POST. items ()), I get <generator object MultiValueDict. items at 0x7f25cb08aa20>, and if print (request.POST. items ('date')) then I get TypeError: items() takes 1 positive argument but 2 were given

Comment: My bad QueryDict.items() return e generator so run `print(list(request.POST.items()))`

Comment: [('pricesum', '3600'), ('date[]', '2021-05-06'), ('price[]', '900')] Он выводит только последнее значение в массиве. Весь массив на скриншоте ниже

Comment: As you can see values are actually there, but have a different name than what you expected. The problem is to understand why these names are different, but for the moment you should be able to access values with `request.POST.get("price[]", False)`

Comment: Why isn't the whole array here? I send one thing and get another

Comment: Then you should edit your question with more details about what you send (the values of variables pricesum, date and price) in your ajax request as well as the details of what you get with `print(list(request.POST.items()))`. Try to reformulate your question : the more details you give, the more accurate answers will be.

Comment: I attached a screenshot with the output of date and price

Comment: Ok cool to know which variables this screenshot refers to, you should explain it in your form. Then start by adding `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` and `dataType: 'json'` as arguments to your ajax POST. Also format your data as a correct JSON with `JSON.stringify({'pricesum': pricesum, 'date': date, 'price': price})`

Comment: Where should I insert it? JSON.stringify({'pricesum': pricesum, 'date': date, 'price': price})

Comment: In your ajax request, set the data argument to this value instead of just your javascript object. Like `data: JSON.stringify({'pricesum': pricesum, 'date': date, 'price': price})`

Comment: `$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "print",
        data: JSON.stringify({'pricesum': pricesum, 'date': date, 'price': price}),
            contentType: 'application/json',
        charset: 'utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,`
I get it in the django function
    `date = request.POST.get('date[]', False)`

Checking it out
    `print(list(request.POST.items()))`
Receive
`[]`

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't understand what's wrong with code with the elements I have

Comment: If not used  `contentType: 'application/json',` and   `charset: 'utf-8',` Then when     `print(list(request.POST.items()))` I get `[('{"pricesum":3600,"date":["2021-04-30","2021-05-02","2021-05-04","2021-05-06"],"price":[1500,450,750,900]}', '')]`(all the array I need) But with  `date = request.POST.get('date[]', False)` I get false. Here it should already be clearer because the array is complete in `print (list(request. POST. items ()))`, and in the receipt it is false

Comment: Now you see the key is `date` not `date[]` anymore so now switch back to `request.POST.get("date", False)` it should work right ?

Comment: No 
`date = request.POST.get('date', False)
    price = request.POST.get('price', False)
    print(list(request.POST.items()))
    print(date)
    print(price)`
Receive

`[('{"pricesum":3600,"date":["2021-04-30","2021-05-02","2021-05-04","2021-05-06"],"price":[1500,450,750,900]}', '')]
False
False`

Comment: Ok then in python `import json` and perform `json.loads(request.body)` to decode your data and get a python dict ?

Comment: Right?

 `json.loads(request.body)
    date = request.POST.get('date', '')
    price = request.POST.get('price', False)
    print(list(request.POST.items()))
    print(date)
    print(price)`
Receive

`[('{"pricesum":3600,"date":["2021-04-30","2021-05-02","2021-05-04","2021-05-06"],"price":[1500,450,750,900]}', '')]
False
False`

Comment: well instead of using `request.POST.get`, use `post_data = json.loads(request.body)`. Then you will have `pricesum = post_data.get("pricesum", False)`, `date = post_data.get("date", False)` and `post_data.get("price", False)`

Comment: Super! Everything works. Thank you very much

Comment: Great ! I will provide an answer for that. Could you please accept it then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussions, it seems that you should stringify your data in your ajax post request.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "print",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'pricesum': pricesum, 'date': date,'price': price,
    })
})
```

Then you can access the data posted by loading the stringified JON into your Python code :

```py
import json

post_data = json.loads(request.body)

pricesum = post_data.get("pricesum", False)
date = post_data.get("date", False)
price = post_data.get("price", False)
```